# Magento - Dynamic lisbox in module edit entries form

Tags: magento

I want to make a dynamic lisbox in the edit form for an entry of a custom table. 
How to edit the file "Edit/Tab/Form.php" for this purpose??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question does not say about where you want to add a dynamic listbox if you want to add in the product edit with its options from your custom data source. You must create a product attribute.

You can see this link for detailed procedure.

http://subesh.com.np/2010/01/creating-custom-sourced-multiselect-product-attribute/

Comment: I have seen your link, it does not help me too unfortunately. It is not a product attribute, but a special table that contains actual gold prices, it helps for the price final calculation...